# Float: Left Not Working on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, css

For the time being, I'm trying to remedy my footer that overlaps my content by specifying `width:100%` and `float:left`, so that it just goes underneath my content.

HOWEVER, on my iPhone, the footer is still overlapping my content... and I can't understand why. I've deleted the cache/etc... and it still overlaps. The CSS worked for another page, but not this page.

**CSS:**

```
html {
    background: #000;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
#container {
    min-width: 900px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#header {
}
.logo {
    font-family: Didot;
    font-size: 4.5em;
    color: #FFF;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}
.main_nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
}
.main_nav li {
    margin: 5px;
}
.main_nav li a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
.main_nav li a:hover {
    color: #06F;
}
#body {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    float: left;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    width: 750px;
    height: 500px;
}
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
.footer_text {
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<head>
<link href="services.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ieservices.css" />
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

  <div id="header">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <ul class="main_nav">
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="body">
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your #body div has a height of 500px - if the content is taller than 500px it is being cut off.

To fix, remove the height setting, or change it to min-height:500px.

Comment: That adds extra unwanted space below the content, though. I'm not sure why, because the `</div>` immediately follows the last character and there's no `&nbsp;` in there.

Comment: Also, why would that have anything to do with the footer?

Comment: There is 100px of padding on the #body div - is this space you're referring to?

    `#body {
     padding-bottom:100px;
     float: left;
     background-color: #f00;
     width: 750px;
     min-height: 500px;
     color: #fff;
 }
 #footer {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100px;
     float: left;
     background: #f09;
 }`

Comment: I've changed the colours above so they stand out (red for the #body and pink for the #footer) and also changed the height to min-height - you can see that there's no space between the div's except for the padding.

Comment: No, I've not yet found anything that fixes this issue.

Comment: @kurzweilguy Could you perhaps post a screenshot that shows what you mean? The above code works perfectly for me...

Comment: @kurzweilguy - hey mate I just checked out your site - it still has it as "Height: 500px" but your content is taller than that which is causing your issue. If you change height to min-height it should fix it.

Comment: I'm working on combining stylesheets, and I'll incorporate that in the next version. Thanks!